# How to do a transition effect on state change with Apache Royale?

Tags: animation, state, effects, apache-royale

I would like to have a transition animation when changing state.

After several tries, I don't see what's the issue.
My first goal is to trigger an alpha effect from 1 to 0 when "Card HOME" is hidden

As there is no **showEffect** or **hideEffect**, I tried with `transitions` property

(**update**: looking at SDK source, I guess I need to add **StatesWithTransitionsImpl**, so I have updated my code, but when clicking on "Description" the "home card" has no transition, it would be fade out, but doesn't working)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<js:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
                xmlns:js="library://ns.apache.org/royale/basic" 
                xmlns="*"
                pageTitle="RoyaleStore">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[   
            import org.apache.royale.core.ValuesManager;


            private function headHome():void
            {
                    initialView.currentState = "HomeState";
            }

            private function headToProducts():void
            {
                    initialView.currentState = "ProductState";                    
            }



        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Style source="main.css"/>

    <js:valuesImpl>
        <js:SimpleCSSValuesImpl />
    </js:valuesImpl>
    <js:beads>
        <js:ApplicationDataBinding />
    </js:beads>

    <js:initialView>
        <js:View >

            <js:beads>
                <js:VerticalLayout />
                <!-- if you comment out this section and comment <fx:Style source="main.css"/> then it isn't working -->
                    <!--  <core:StatesWithTransitionsImpl/>
                    <utils:EffectTimer/>-->
            </js:beads>

            <js:states>
                <js:State name="HomeState"  />
                <js:State name="ProductState"  />
            </js:states>

            <js:transitions>
                <js:Transition fromState="HomeState" toState="*">
                    <js:Fade target="homeView" alphaFrom="1" alphaTo="0" duration="1000" />
                </js:Transition>
                <js:Transition fromState="*" toState="HomeState">
                     <js:Fade target="homeView" alphaFrom="0" alphaTo="1" duration="1000" />
                </js:Transition>
                <js:Transition fromState="ProductState" toState="*">
                    <js:Fade target="productView" alphaFrom="1" alphaTo="0" duration="1000" />
                </js:Transition>
                <js:Transition fromState="*" toState="ProductState">
                    <js:Fade target="productView" alphaFrom="0" alphaTo="1" duration="1000" />
                </js:Transition>
            </js:transitions>


            <js:Group>
                <js:beads>
                    <js:HorizontalLayout />
                </js:beads>
                <js:TextButton text="Home" click="headHome()" />
                <js:TextButton text="Products" click="headToProducts()"/>
            </js:Group>

            <js:Group>
                 <js:Label id="productView" text="productView" includeIn="ProductState"  />
                 <js:Label id="homeView" text="homeView" includeIn="HomeState" />
            </js:Group>

        </js:View>        
    </js:initialView>    
</js:Application>
```

How to do it working ?

(**update 2** : I have updated the code using part of exemple of Royale Store. It is working when clicking on "Home" but strangely **not when clic on "Products"**. Bug or not ?)

I found that to work you must include main.css with :

```
@namespace basic "library://ns.apache.org/royale/basic";

global {
    IStatesImpl:            ClassReference("org.apache.royale.core.StatesWithTransitionsImpl");
    IEffectTimer:           ClassReference("org.apache.royale.utils.EffectTimer");
}
```

Another problem is that if I try to add beads like this :

```
 <js:beads>
       <core:StatesWithTransitionsImpl/>
       <utils:EffectTimer/>
 </js:beads>
```

(and remove including main.css) then it isn't working...

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Checkout examples/royale/RoyaleStore.  It is using state transitions.

Comment: Thanks, Effectly, it help me, now it is working an half... Trying to simplify the code, I ask mylself if there is a bug or not. I have updated the code in the question

Comment: Regarding using StatesWithTransitionsImpl in CSS vs in the js:beads list (on a strand):  beads applied in js:beads are like styles added to an HTMLElement via the styles attribute.  They are only seen by the instance you apply them to, where as in CSS any HTMLElement can lookup the appropriate style.  The various containers will look for an IStatesImpl on js:beads then in the CSS.  If you only apply the IStatesImpl to a specific instance then other instances won't see it.